# Laragon-can't detect my laravel project

Tags: php, mysql, apache, laravel-5, laragon

I am trying to learn how to work with Laravel. I successfully installed Laravel through Laragon. The process that I followed-

Menu->Quick Create->Laravel->(Gave a Project name-laravel_CRUD)->Ok.

Then everything was installed and created successfully including database and dependencies were successfully updated. A pretty url was also generated as this format: http://laravel_CRUD.dev. But whenever I pasted this URL into my browser's URL bar, it didn't work and showed:

> The site can't be reached

Obviously Apache and MySQL were started. I stopped those and restart those again. But still it failed to detect my project.

What's wrong with it?

Answer (score 1):

The Laragon can not run your Laravel app if you use `_` in your app installation folder.

Like you have used `laravel_CRUD`, instead you can use `-`. So, your app url should look like `http://laravel-CRUD.dev` . I'm hoping it will work.

Further, if you face any problem, Please leave a comment below.